# Combining change and chained jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, chained

I'm trying to create a simple chained (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) select box that ends in calling a page, and have used two snippets of code found on this site, but i'm having real trouble combining the two.
Here's my script:

```
$(function() { 
 $("#classifications").chained("#rounds");
    $("#classifications").change(function(){
  $("#result").load( $(this).val() );
});
});
```

and my html:

```
<select id="rounds">
<option value="">select round</option>
  <option value="metric">Metric</option>
  <option value="imperial">Imperial</option>
</select>
<select id="classifications">
  <option value="">Select Classification</option>
  <option value="test1.html" class="metric">Gents Metric</option>
  <option  value="test2.html" class="metric">Ladies Metric</option>
  <option  value="test3.html" class="metric">Juniors Metric</option>
  <option value="test5.html" class="imperial">Gents Imperial</option>
  <option value="test6.html" class="imperial">Ladies Imperial</option>
  <option value="test4.html" class="imperial">Juniors Imperial</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

It should be straightforward but I can't find where i'm going wrong? It works but results in the select boxes being repeated.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what the `chained()` function does ?

Comment: Are an errors raised or messages logged in the console? Does anything happen?

Comment: Why not `$("#classifications, #rounds")`?

Comment: What do you mean by the select boxes are repeated, it seems to work just fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/jtUtV/

Comment: @adeneo: it doesn't work outside of jsFiddle without adding another  `#rounds` and `#classifications` select elements.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. @adeneo - chained is a js plugin for chaining select boxes found here http://goo.gl/42Zw0 and by repeat I mean upon changing the first select - rounds, two duplicate select boxes appear below in Safari and FF (Mac)  I get a huge memory leak in FF and Safari resulting in a force quit so can't get to an error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `chained()` plugin, try commenting out [line 54 from the source](http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.chained.js) which should be:

```
$(self).trigger("change");
```

I did that and everything works as expected. I haven't expanded it to more than 2 selects so if that's something you need, you should work through that.

Comment: thank you for your code - it does call the results but doesn't chain the selects unfortunately, it just disables the second select, i think? I have over 45 variables i need to chain over 3 select boxes ending in a page call, so i'm trying to find the simplest method. As you can guess my js knowledge is limited!

Comment: You are brilliant! Thank you so much that works great and I even think i understand why!